# DateTime Parse unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, datetime

I have to convert / parse a string into a DateTime

```
DateTime resultDate = new DateTime(2000,01,01);
string input = "24.24.2000";

string format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(input, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out resultDate);
```

now if the string is invalid and the conversion fails (in this example the 24 isn't a valid month) the Method `TryParseExact` changes the variable `resultDate` into `DateTime.Min`.

Why should I want to have `DateTime.Min` instead of the origin value if the conversion fails?

Comment: The documentation for [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) states that this is the *expected* behavior. If this is not desirable simply handle with a conditional statement dependent on the value of the return value (`success`).

Comment: @DrSnail all `TryParseXXX` methods have *out* parameters. This means *they always* assign a value

Comment: In fact, you *had* to use the `out` keyword in order to pass `resultDate` to the method. This isn't unexpected behaviour, the language went out of its way to make it clear that the method would replace the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't actually related to `DateTime.TryParseExact` nor is it unexpected behaviour. The result is an `out` parameter which means the *method* will always assign a value to it. The language actually requires the `out` keyword to avoid any confusion. `out` parameters are expected to be empty, which is why you can declare them without assigning a value.

A method's code can't even try to *read* an `out` parameter without initializing it to something. The following example will fail compilation with `Use of unassigned out parameter 'result'`:

```
bool TryParse(string text,out DateTime result)
{
    var original=result;    //this fails compilation
    result=DateTime.Today;
    return true;
}
```

An `out` parameter is *always* assigned by the method unless the method throws an exception.

The documentation of [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) explains what the default value will be if conversion fails. It also explains that the parameter should be passed uninitialized

> When this method returns, contains the DateTime value equivalent to
> the date and time contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or
> MinValue if the conversion failed. The conversion fails if either the
> s or format parameter is null, is an empty string, or does not contain
> a date and time that correspond to the pattern specified in format.
>
> This parameter is passed uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

> Why should I want to have DateTime.Min instead of the origin value if the conversion fails

Because that is what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) states will happen.

> When this method returns, contains the DateTime value equivalent to the date and time contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, **or MinValue if the conversion failed**.

---

With a simple modification to your code you can take advantage of the result and not have to repeat your default value.

```
DateTime resultDate;
string input = "24.24.2000";
string format = "dd.MM.yyyy";

if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(input, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out resultDate))
    resultDate = new DateTime(2000,01,01);
```